# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm

I get this error when I try and close views in our silverlight application with an MVVM framework

Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Here is my code:

```
ObservableCollection<IViewModel> _viewModels = new ObservableCollection<IViewModel>();

        var _viewManager = AppContext.Current.ViewService.GetViewManager("Main");
        var _views = _viewManager.OpenViews;

        _viewModels = _views;

        foreach (var _vm in _viewModels)
        {
            _viewManager.CloseView(_vm);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wound up using a for loop -

```
var viewManager = AppContext.Current.ViewService.GetViewManager("Main");
var views = viewManager.OpenViews;

for (int i = views.Count -1; i < views.Count; i--)
{
    if(i == -1)
    {
        return;
    }
    viewManager.CloseView(_views[i]);
}
```

worked my way backwards through my _view count.

Answer (score 7):

You **cannot modify** a collection that is being iterated over using `foreach`.

`CloseView(_vm)` seems to remove an element from the `ObservableCollection`.

Answer (score 4):

While Marius Schulz is perfectly right, the simple solution is to create a new collection with the data you wish to remove, or using a for(;;) loop instead of foreach.

```
// using Linq's ToArray() to create a new collection
foreach (var _vm in _viewModels.ToArray()) 
{
    _viewManager.CloseView(_vm);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help and I agree with the premise of not using a foreach - i am working my way through using a for loop. this seems to be the way to go.

Comment: Be careful with for loop. It might cause you to skip some entries if you delete something from the collection while iterating.

Comment: With for loops, best to loop starting from the end of the collection. Although, I wouldn't recommend in this case as you are having the viewManager do the deletion which you cannot assume the order is the same as the one in the loop. But if you are 100% sure then it shouldn't be an issue

Comment: @svick: That was the whole point of calling `ToArray()`, to make sure that we are not iterating through the actual collection directly (or indirectly).  Using it creates a copy of the elements into a separate collection which itself is not being modified.